# Extract an XML in String format from an XmlStreamReader

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, reader

Good afternoon, I'm telling you, it turns out that I'm trying to extract the entire xml in String format from within an XMLStreamReader, the point is that after not getting it, it seems that I found an example that works for people, which is the following:

```
public String getOuterXml(XMLStreamReader xmlr) throws TransformerConfigurationException,
         TransformerFactoryConfigurationError, TransformerException {
             Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
             StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
             transformer.transform(new StAXSource(xmlr), new StreamResult(stringWriter));
             return stringWriter.toString();
         }
```

But it turns out that it returns this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: StAXSource(XMLStreamReader) with XMLStreamReadernot in XMLStreamConstants.START_DOCUMENT or XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT state
```

The point is that I don't understand why this exception is thrown or how to solve it. If someone could explain to me why it happens, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Have you used 'xmlr' prior to calling that method? It seems to think you could have. If you have - you can't do that

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add a sample of the xml file.